# Nodejs Express framework route to a file

Tags: node.js, express

New to express, wondering what is the best way to route to a single file in my directory. For example here is my simple server directory structure:

```
http://mywebroot.com
    |
    myfolder
    asset
        |
        log.txt
```

So I would like to have log.txt file being open on my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways you could do this (maybe more, I'm not a Node Pro yet).

First, you could serve the file statically with:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //put file in /public
```

Or you could use the `fs` module and read it in.

```
app.get("/fileRoute",function(req,res) {
    fs.readFile("./path/to/file.ext","utf8",function(err,html) {
        res.send(html);
    });
});
```

Personally I suggest just serving `log.txt` statically in a public folder.